# How to attach our own Menu to Eclipse Workbench Default Menu Bar?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How can I attach my own created menu to eclipse workbench default menubar programmatically so that I export the desired RCP application with view as a plugin and my Declared Menu is also shown in the Workbench Menubar?

Kindly Provide any Code, if anyone has for better understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can manage that in your `plugin.xml`. Look in [eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_menus.html) and [wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions). Also [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html)

Comment: but i need it to be done programatically **without touching plugin.xml**. is there any way out using in ActionbarAdvisor or View.java?? i tried hard but still unsuccessfull

Comment: may be [that](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/03/commands-menu-runtime/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for you help but still it's not quite Relevant,is there no way that without modfying plugin.xml i can attahc my menu to eclipse workbench menubar

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following without touching the `plugin.xml`

I added the code within the `start(BundleContext context)` method of the plugin Activator class, and it worked fine. Eclipse wiki has some more documentation on the [Menu API](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Search_Menu#Menus_API).

```
final IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);

AbstractContributionFactory contributionFactory = new AbstractContributionFactory(
        "menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu", null) {

    @Override
    public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IContributionRoot additions) {
        MenuManager myMenu = new MenuManager("MyMenu", "my.menu.id");

        // Add your own contribution items here.
        myMenu.add(new Action("Test Menu Item") {
        });

        additions.addContributionItem(myMenu, null);
    }
};

menuService.addContributionFactory(contributionFactory);
```